# Python не видит фотографию в папке

Tags: python

Работаю с библиотекой Pygame.
Как исправить ошибку:
Путь с фотографиями: C:\Users\me\PycharmProjects\main\PyGame\data
Путь с кодом: C:\Users\me\PycharmProjects\main\PyGame\Game\main.py

В папке data лежат фотографии
При попытке открыть фотографию из папки data, возникает ошибка:

```
FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory.
```

Код в main.py:

```
def download(name_of_photo):
    path = os.path.join('data', name_of_photo)
    im = pygame.image.load(path)
    return im
```

Почему питон не видит фото?

Comment: Потому что, видимо, в **рабочей** директории нет такого пути.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, что Ваша папка находится не в директории с файлом, а на директории выше. А вы к существующему пути добавляете `data` и в итоге выходит `C:\Users\me\PycharmProjects\main\PyGame\Game\data`

Comment: в каком формате нужно указать папку с фотографиями, чтобы не возникала ошибка?

Comment: @Евгений, эм... Обычная папка в Windows.

Comment: проект на гитхабе, там не имеется возможность изменить структуру в репозитории